# Added some regex into existing regular pattern

Tags: regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am not good regex and need to update following pattern without impacting other pattern. Any suggestion $ sign contain 1t0 4. $ sign always be begining of the line.( space may or may not be)

```
import re
data = " $$$AKL_M0_90_2K: Two line end vias (VIAG, VIAT and/or" 
patt = '^ (?:ABC *)?([A-Za-z0-9/\._\:]+)\s*: ? '
match = re.findall( patt, data, re.M )
print match
```

> Note : data is multi line string
>
> match should contain : "$$$AKL_M0_90_2K" this result

Comment: let me know if it's not clear still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following solution (see [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/FYUNze)):

```
import re
data = r" $$$AKL_M0_90_2K: Two line end vias (VIAG, VIAT and/or" 
patt = r'^\s*([$]{1,4}[^:]+)'
match = re.findall( patt, data, re.M )
print(match)
```

The `re.findall` will return the list with just one match. The `^\s*([$]{1,4}[^:]+)` regex matches:

- `^` - start of a line (you use `re.M`)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([$]{1,4}[^:]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 to 4 `$` symbols,  and then one or more characters other than `:`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gP1bO2/1)

**If you need to keep your own regex**, just do one of the following:

- Add `$` to the character class ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/gP1bO2/2)): `^ (?:ABC *)?([$A-Za-z0-9/._:]+)\s*: ?`
- Add an alternative to the first non-capturing group and place it at the start of the capturing one ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/gP1bO2/4)): `^ ((?:ABC *|[$]{1,4})?[A-Za-z0-9/._:]+)\s*: ?`

Comment: I was trying to add into this exiting one so other rule will not impact. is it possible. I mean add more into existing one "patt = '^ (?:ABC *)? (\s*)?([A-Za-z0-9/\._\:]+)\s*: ? '" like way

Comment: I added two more solutions based on your own regex. Note the `.` and `:` inside a character class do not have to be escaped. `:` does not have to be escaped anywhere in a Python regex.

Comment: Thx for nice explanation